# How to add custom fields in Apache Solr's search result?

Tags: search, entities

I'm trying to add some custom fields(image field, text field) in Apache Solr's search result.
I ended up found the code below; however, I don't know:

1. Where to put this code (is it template.php?)
2. How to get the information to display them.

`

```
function mymodule_apachesolr_update_index($document, $node, $namespace) {
  // When indexing nodes, add field from my custom content type.
  if ($node->type === 'my_contenttype') {
    // Grab the image URI and the description.
    $image_uri = $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'];
    $description = $node->field_description['und'][0]['safe_value'];
    // Add the image and description to the document in the solr index.
    $document->addField('ss_my_contenttype_image', $image_uri);
    $document->addField('ts_my_contenttype_description', $description);
  }
}

function mymodule_apachesolr_query_prepare($query) {
  // Add the image.
  $query->addParam('fl', 'ss_my_contenttype_image');
  // Add the description text.
  $query->addParam('fl', 'ts_my_contenttype_description');
}
```

I appreciate any advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you have D7 and latest Solr search integration module then you can follow these steps:

- Create a custom module with the following code (If your field is single value text then you should add "ts_" prefix to its name.)

  ```
  function mymodule_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
    $query->addParam('fl', 'ts_field_name');
  }
  ```
- Add the following function in the template.php file

  ```
  function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
    $variables['ts_field_name'] = $variables['result']['fields']['ts_field_name'];
  }
  ```
- Display the field in search-result.tpl.php

  ```
  <?php if ($ts_field_name): ?>
    <?php print $ts_field_name; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

This is a quick way that doesn't use any  theme function like `theme_apachesolr_search_snippets()` for search results snippets.

You can find more information here:

- http://archive.org/details/ApacheSolrSearchMastery_250
- http://www.slideshare.net/AcquiaInc/apache-solr-search-mastery

Answer (score 0):

Those functions would go to a custom module, in this case named mymodule.module. You can dig out the queried fields in your theme, either in template.php (in mytheme_preprocess_search_result(), where you would typically perhaps process the fields further and modify the $variables array to include the modified fields) or in your search-result.tpl.php directly.