# Apache Solr Search, add taxonomy field in search results

Tags: 7, entities, search

I'm really bumping my head on this.

I *simply* need to add tids from a term reference field on nodes returned by a solr search result.

It's a unique term reference.

I looked for the field in solr console and it's 'im_field_arbo'.

I followed [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30003/how-to-add-custom-fields-in-apache-solrs-search-result) and [that](https://drupal.org/node/1490186) and came to this :

1.

```
    function MYMODULE_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {
      if(isset($entity->field_arbo)) {
        $document->addField('im_field_arbo', $entity->field_arbo['und'][0]['tid']);
      }
    }
```

This doesn't throw back any errors.

2.

Then, to retrieve it, I tried either **hook_apachesolr_query_alter**, **hook_apachesolr_query_prepare** with :

```
    $query->addParam('im', 'im_field_arbo');
```

and **hook_apachesolr_modify_query** with :

```
    $params['im'] .= ',im_field_arbo';
```

---

Still, no trace of my field in my search results.

Any help ? Thx very much.

---

### Update

I think my field is well indexed : `_apachesolr_index_document_build_node` works like a charm.

**Now the question is : "How do I get them back in search results ?"**

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful, but your code should work (with the `addParam()` method in `hook_apachesolr_query_alter()`). I have a nearly identical setup, just using a different field name, and it works great

Comment: Tell a lie, I'm actually using a hook named `hook_apachesolr_index_document_build_node()`, with `_node` on the end. Might be worth changing that, clearing the cache, and giving it a try

Comment: Thx @Clive , but still nothing... No error though *(after I removed "entity_type" from index_document_build_node's args)*.

Answer (score 2):

To show the field you have added to your Solr index you first need to add it to the search result. Add this to template.php

```
function template_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $variables['im_field_arbo'] = $variables['result']['fields']['im_field_arbo'];
}
```

Then in your `search-result.tpl.php` you can access the field like this:

```
<?php if ($im_field_arbo): ?>
  <?php print $im_field_arbo; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thx. Very weird : I can't get that function to act on search... Nor var_dump, dpm, even kill won't be fired. In my theme's template.php, either with template_preprocess_search_result or *my_theme*_preprocess_search_result... Any help ?

Comment: update : I of course checked preprocessing, with __template_preprocess_*mymodule*_results__, and no trace of the field in $variables.

Comment: You need to put the function template_preprocess_search_result in your themes template.php file. Rename template with the name of your theme.

Comment: Tried it already :(

Comment: Still nothing ; does it work also with solr search ?

Comment: That function should be called `THEMENAME_preprocess_search_result`, not `template_preprocess_...`, if you're using search API solr or Apachesolr modules then you should definitely see it being invoked

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_apachesolr_process_results().
 */
function mymodule_apachesolr_process_results(&$results) {
  foreach ($results as $key => &$result) {
    $result['foo'] = $result['node']->im_field_arbo;
  }
}
```

Call this variable in you search-result.tpl.php
e.g.

```
<?php print $result['foo']; ?>
```

I think this code will work with the combination of:

```
function mymodule_apachesolr_query_alter(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  $query->addParam('fl', 'im_field_arbo');
}

function mymodule_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type) {
  // I think you should do a foreach here, since you are using multi-valued field.
  foreach ($entity->field_arbo[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $val) {
    $tid = $val['tid'];
    // The 1st letter indicates the data type and the last letter is
    // 'm' for multi-valued.
    $document->addField('im_field_arbo', $tid);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.